# É possível executar o puppeteer em headless mode via ajax?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, puppeteer

Bem, estou precisando usar o puppeteer na minha extensão do Chrome. Eu estava procurando maneiras de fazer isso e encontrei o puppeteer-web, é um puppeteer empacotado, e usando-o por alguns dias percebi que ele não pode executar o puppeteer em modo headless. Então, desisti de executar o puppeteer-web e tentei executar pela minha extensão da seguinte maneira:

Abrir um servidor node.js local que consegue de fato executar o puppeteer em modo headless
e ai a extensão faz uma requisição ajax para essa aplicação a fim de executá-la.

App.js => Esse é o código que executa o server e chama a função que executará o puppeteer:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
var $ = require('jquery');
const pages = require('./pages');
const server = express();
var router = express.Router();

router.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET,POST,OPTIONS");
  next();
 }); //here I tried to solve the "method not allowed". it not works.


server 
.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))
.use(express.static('public'))
//set the path of the jquery file to be used from the node_module jquery package
.use('/jquery',express.static(path.join(__dirname+'/node_modules/jquery/dist/')))

.set('views',path.join(__dirname,"views"))
.set('view engine','hbs')
 
.get('/', pages.index)
 
.listen(process.env.PORT || 5502)
```

pages.js => código que executa o puppeteer:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const path = require('path');


module.exports = {
    index: async function follow(){
            try{
                
            // Aqui cria uma instÂncia no browser
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                headless:true,
                args:["--no-sandbox",'--disable-setuid-sandbox']
                
            });
        
            // Aqui carrega a página
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0); //seta tempo ilimitado de espera
            await page.goto("https://www.instagram.com/");

            [....]
}
```

test.html => Parte front-end que faz a solicitação:

```
<script>
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = () => {
            if(xhr.status === 200){
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }else{
                console.log("erro")
            }
        }
        xhr.open("POST", "../src/pages.js");
        xhr.send(null);

        
    </script>
```

Ao final de tudo, a requisição imprimiu no console: "405 (Method Not Allowed)"

alguém sabe como fazer isso? É possível?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou responder a sua pergunta de modo geral. Infelizmente é complicado de verificar junto ao seu código e o erro que você informou. O erro em questão provavelmente seu servidor ou back-end (express) está bloqueando requisições POST, e não é um erro relacionado diretamente à pergunta e ao puppeteer.

De modo geral, sim é possível realizar uma requisição para o back-end e executar um puppeteer em modo headless no servidor.

Algumas bibliotecas deverão ser instaladas no servidor, veja [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979188/error-failed-to-launch-the-%20browser-process-puppeteer)

Você deverá verificar a compatibilidade das bibliotecas necessárias de acordo com o servidor que você estará utilizando.

Dependendo de onde vocês hospedar, pode haver limitações no servidor que o puppeteer deverá ser adaptado e testado, como por exemplo aceleração de GPU, etc.

Outra biblioteca que é interessante de verificar é a [puppeteer-cluster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-cluster)

Com ela, você possui um cluster de headless browsers e te ajuda a monitorar, configurar e utilizar o puppeteer de forma assíncrona utilizando filas. Novamente é bom verificar o servidor, suas limitações, pois dependendo da quantidade de headless browsers que serão executados, e o que mais existe no servidor, pode ser que ele seja sobrecarregado.

Em minha pouca experiência, vi que acaba consumindo uma quantidade relativamente grande de memória e CPU, especialmente quando mais de um headless browser é executado de uma só vez.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: "De modo geral, sim é possível realizar uma requisição para o back-end e executar um puppeteer em modo headless no servidor." É isso mesmo o que quero. você por gentileza faz alguma ideia de como fazer isso?